# Help with using ‘auf sich nehmen’

Tags: word-usage, phrase

*Auf sich nehmen* means to accept, shoulder something.

Is the following correct?

> Ich habe mich auf Bürde genommen.

If not, could you please use it in a sentence where *I* is the subject?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like you said, *auf sich nehmen* means to accept or shoulder something. However, in your translation there isn’t any *auf*.

Man würde auch nicht viele Bürde sagen. Du kannst *viele Bürden* (lots of things) sagen oder *eine große Bürde* for one big thing to shoulder.

> Ich habe eine große Bürde auf mich genommen.